# Conversão de string em double C++

Tags: c++

Gostaria de converter uma `string` passada para valor do tipo `double`.

Exemplo:

```
string expressao = "1+1";
double x, y;
```

Tal que, `x = expressao[0];` e `y = expressao[1];`

E a soma de `x+y` retornasse *2* como resposta.

Já li algumas coisas sobre `atof`, mas não consegui aplicá-lo corretamente.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

double resultado(string); // prototipo

int main()
{
    string expressao;

    cout << "Exemplo de Expressão:\n\n1+2\n\n";
    cout << "Insira uma expressão:";
    getline(cin, expressao);

    cout << expressao << " = " << resultado(expressao) << endl;
}

double resultado(string valor) {
    double x, y;
/*
    gostaria de recuperar apenas os valores numericos. Por exemplo:
    Se a minha entrada for 1+1
    gostaria repartir a entrada(1+1) em duas partes.
    1. valor[0] para recuperar o valor 1
    2. valor[1] para recuperar o outro valor 1 depois do sinal(+)
    3. em seguida gostaria de converter esses dois char(valor[0] e valor[1]) em valores do tipo double par assim, somá-los e retorná-los.
*/
    return x;
/*
    if (opr[1] == '+') { 
    return x+y;
    } else if (opr[1] == '-') {
        return x-y;
    } else if (opr[1] == '*') {
        return x*y;
    } else if (opr[1] == '/') {
        return x/y;
    } else {
        return 0.0;
    }
*/
}
```

Comment: Gostaria de converter para double essas duas partes recuperadas através da string.

double x, y;
string expressao = "1+1"; // entrada
x = expressao[0]; // valor 1 que está no formato char 
y = expressao[1]; // valor 2 que está no formato char 

me compreende?

Comment: Poste a parte de como você está recuperando as partes, para facilitar.

Comment: É, aí já dá pra ver que o problema é bem diferente da pergunta inicial. Veja aqui como formatar sua pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/markdown

Comment: Postei uma foto agora pra ajudar. O objetivo é pegar dois chars a partir de uma string, converter esses chars em doubles e em seguida somá-los.

Comment: valeu pela dica Bacco... olhando aqui.

Comment: Na verdade é preferível o código em texto do que o printscreen, mas lendo este help fica fácil você adaptar.

Comment: Não consegui editar todo :/

Comment: Deixe 4 espaços antes de cada linha do código, que fica legal. Tem o botão `{ }` que ja faz isso automaticamente. Selecione a parte que é código e aperte o `{ }`

Comment: Pronto. agora consegui

Comment: Você pode ver em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/18807/revisions quem realmente conseguiu editar. Torço para você conseguir na próxima.

Comment: Ahh... rsrs obrigado bigown e Bacco :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se é algo assim que você procura.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

double resultado(std::string valor)
{
    std::istringstream iss(valor);
    int X, Y;

    iss >> X >> Y;
    return X + Y;
}

int main()
{
    double z = resultado("1+2");

    std::cout << z << std::endl;
}
```

### [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/vTeXKl)

Comment: Exatamente isso Ideone :).

Comment: Poderia me explicar o que acontece com o sinal(+) no código? Pelo que vejo, foi possível receber os dois inteiros sem a interferência do sinal.

Comment: Ah, entendi. Ele captura por fluxo. Obrigado :)

Comment: @Sunstreaker Na verdade o sinal não é ignorado não. O que acontece nesse exemplo é que X lê "1" e Y lê "+2" que é uma notação válida para um número. Para ver que ele não esta ignorando basta trocar o sinal para algo que não é válido como número, por exemplo "1&2". Nesse caso ele não vai conseguir ler o segundo número. Exemplo: http://ideone.com/hwfpUv